# Why should I buy new outfits?

Tags: assassins-creed-origins

At the start of any RPG-like game, I would only purchase items and gear that would make me stronger and makes trekking through the game a lot easier. One of the things I could buy are new outfits. Interestingly they have rarities just like weapons and armor do.

As far as I can see, outfits are just cosmetic but the rarities makes me think that there might be something else to them. There's no description or other indication of stat benefits at the stores so maybe not.

Why should I buy new outfits?  Are they *just* there purely for cosmetic reasons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they exist purely for the cosmetic reasons. I tried different outfits from the `Ubisoft Club` store and in-game store to confirm it.

As far as I can see, no visible stat like health point/attack power or hidden stat such as running or climbing speed applied to my character. I tried following outfits;

- Ezio's Outfit
- Altaïr's Outfit
- Mummies
- Scarab Soldier

to observe some changes to my stats, nothing changed.

It didn't boost my climbing speed. My horse and camel are at the same velocity. It didn't raise my health point, range power or melee power. I did not receive any discount from the merchants either.

Now back to your original question:

## Why should you buy it?

As you are aware, photo mode exists in the game. You can take pictures inside the game which will be available for other players who will get to see and like your photograph. Then you may wish different outfits for your character. After all, some players, like me, would like their character to be seen with different styles.

As @Flater suggested, I did test several outfits to approach enemies by both ambushings and to walk straight towards them several times and quite honestly, it didn't help my detection meter in any way. I tried it both in cities, deserts in both day and night. Once I was spotted or noticed, the threat meter was almost always at the same level. I do not think your gears camouflages you as you would otherwise believe.

Gears tested for this purpose:

- Centurion's Armor
- Desert Cobra
- Ezio's Outfit
- Altaïr's Outfit
- Mummies
- Sekhmet Costume
- Scarab Soldier
- Bayek's Outfit
- Bathhouse Towel

Comment: You checked stat changes, did you happen to check if there's a difference in detection by enemies? That would make some sense, and could be a reason to have different outfits for different regions (didn't Ezio have end-game capes to the same effect in one of the games?)

Comment: @Flater Check my updated answer